Sencha Cmd ERR generate App (Trial Version)
I successfully install Sencha CMD CLI(getting started with zip).
Bunt when I try to generate an ExtJS app with my trial installation it fails. It worked in the beginning. Here is what I get:
C:\Users\LG\Desktop\sencha>sencha generate app --ext MyApp ./MyApp
Sencha Cmd v7.8.0.59
[ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for "ext"!
[ERR]    The following versions cannot be satisfied:
[ERR]       root: ext@5- (No matches!)
[ERR] Cannot resolve package requirements

C:\Users\LG\Desktop\sencha>

I ran cmd with  "Run as Administrator" mode
Any suggestion to solve the error?
I ran cmd with  "Run as Administrator" mode.
And I also unstalled sencha cmd and reinstalled it.
But it couldn't work.

Have you downloaded and installed the ext framework as well?

No, I downloaded trial installation so it just had cmd installation. I thought that
" sencha generate app --ext MyApp ./MyApp "
means automatically download the Ext JS Commercial Trial package and use it to generate my application(MyApp).

I unstalled Sencha cmd, removed sench cmd folder and downloaded sencha cmd installation zip for trial user. Then I sucessfully installed Sencha CMD and can generate app.

You have to download and install Sencha CMD.
After that you either get a trial of ExtJS or npm ExtJS.
Trial of ExtJS

Create a folder "src" and cd into the folder
Extract the ExtJS version here (or npm it here) and cd into the folder
Terminal: sencha generate workspace ../workspace

By this you generate the following structure:
src
 | - workspace
   | - ext
 | - ext sources

now cd into src.workspace and type
sencha generate app --ext Demo ./apps/demo --modern
cd intot apps.demo and type
sencha app watch and type into your browser localhost:1841/apps/demo
Links
basic trail install: https://www.sencha.com/ext-js-quick-start-guide/
workspace and app: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.8.0/guides/workspaces.html
